# How to use Box API with .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, box, coreclr

I am building Web.API application using `ASP.Net Core` platform.  My application  needs to authenticate with Box and then download the file from box server. 
I see Box has Nuget packages for classic .Net [here](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2) However i couldn't find any compatible Box Nuget pckages for ASP.Net Core?

May be they are not available yet from the BOX team. Then so how do I authenticate and download file using "Build on Box Platform" and .Net Core?

I am assuming I have to use HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anyone has built a box-specific .NET Core package. Still, you should be able to. Like you guessed, you'll need HttpClient. In core, you'll need to add Microsoft.Net.Http.Client for it. Beyond that, you'll need to get the authentication working. Fortunately, Box uses OAuth, which is really widely used. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth should provide you with everything you need for that. [This linkedin tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/authenticating-a-user-with-linkedin-in-aspnet-core/) should give you a good starting point on how to do that. Other than that, you really don't need a third party library to get any of this going, so you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the GitHub, it supports Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 and 8.1, so chances are, it already may run on .NET Core too. There is no `netstandard-1.x` or `netcoreapp1.x` target, which means you can't just add it to project.json w/o getting a "Platform not supported" error.

But you can do something like this to forge nuget to install Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8.x libraries and see if it runs.

```
"framework":
{
    "netstandard1.6" : 
    {
         "imports": [ "portable-net45+wp8+wpa81" ],
         "dependencies": 
         {
             "Box.V2" : "2.12.1"
         }
    }
}
```

Alternatively use `netcoreapp1.0` if it's your main project (web project or console application). Then try to use it and see if it works or not.

Just be careful when using `imports`, because it overrides NuGet target framework checking and the above will allow you to install any Windows Phone 8 or 8.1 library, even the ones which have Windows Phone UI controls for XAML. These of course won't work.

Only Windows 8 and Windows Phone/Mobile libraries that do not use any of Windows or Windows Phone/Mobile API (like GPS etc.), may have a chance to run in .NET Core. Good candidates are APIs that only connect through HttpClient or compression libraries which run on Windows Phone/Mobile.

Alternatively to all the above: Grab the source from GitHub, put it into a .NET Core Class Library (with *.xproj), and target `netcoreapp1.0` and `netlibrary1.6` (or lower) and see if it compiles. If it does, create a nuget package and include it in your project.